# Combining multiple SELECT queries in one

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

As the title says the query needs to combine multiple select queries. The question is as follows:

**Display the total number of employees, and of that total the number of employees hired in 1995,1996,1997,1998.**

My query:

```
select (select count(*) from employees) as "Total",
       (select count(*) from employees where hire_date between 'JAN-1-0095' and 'DEC-1-0095')as "1995",
       (select count(*) from employees where hire_date between 'JAN-1-0096' and 'DEC-1-0096') as "1996",
       (select count(*) from employees where hire_date between 'JAN-1-0097' and 'DEC-1-0097') as "1997",
       (select count(*) from employees where hire_date between 'JAN-1-0098' and 'DEC-1-0098') as "1998" 
from employees
```

but the issue is instead of returning only single record this query is being executed for all the records in the table and hence producing the following output:

[image]

Comment: The problem with your query is that you're selecting from Employees, so you're getting a result for every row in Employees. Change the last `from employees` to `from dual` and it should work. That said, take @ahorsewithnoname's advice about the dates. Also note that the way horse's query works is more generally useful for other scenarios than your series of subqueries.

Comment: okay i get it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the years are really what you want, the problem with your query is that you are selecting from `employees`, so you get a row for each one.  You could use:

```
select (select count(*) from employees) as "Total",
       (select count(*) from employees where hire_date between 'JAN-1-0095' and 'DEC-1-0095')as "1995",
       (select count(*) from employees where hire_date between 'JAN-1-0096' and 'DEC-1-0096') as "1996",
       (select count(*) from employees where hire_date between 'JAN-1-0097' and 'DEC-1-0097') as "1997",
       (select count(*) from employees where hire_date between 'JAN-1-0098' and 'DEC-1-0098') as "1998" 
from dual;
```

And I would use `date '1998-01-01'` for the date constants.

However, I prefer @a_horse_with_no_name's solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional counting:

```
select count(*) as total_count, 
       count(case when extract(year from hire_date) = 1995 then 1 end) as "1995",
       count(case when extract(year from hire_date) = 1996 then 1 end) as "1996",
       count(case when extract(year from hire_date) = 1997 then 1 end) as "1997",
       count(case when extract(year from hire_date) = 1998 then 1 end) as "1997",
from employees;
```

this makes use of the fact that aggregate functions ignore NULL values and therefor the `count()` will only count those rows where the `case` expressions returns a non-null value.

---

Your query returns one row for each row in the employees table because you do not apply any grouping. Each select is a scalar sub-select that gets executed for each and every row in the `employees` table.

You *could* make it only return a single row if you replace the final `from employees` with `from dual` - but you'd still count over all rows within each sub-select.

---

You should also avoid implicit data type conversion like you did. `'JAN-1-0095'` is a string and will implicitly be converted to a `date` depending on your NLS settings. Your query would not run if executed from my computer (because of different NLS settings).

As you are looking for a complete year, just comparing the year is a bit shorter to write and easier to understand (at least in my eyes).

Another option would be to use proper date literals, e.g. `where hire_date between DATE '1995-01-01' and DATE '1995-12-31'` or a bit more verbose using Oracle's `to_date()` function: `where hire_date between to_date('1995-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('1995-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using a lot of subqueries. You should try this:

---

SQL Server:

```
SELECT count(*) as Total, hire_date 
FROM employees
WHERE year(hire_date) IN ('1995','1996','1997','1998') 
GROUP BY hire_date WITH CUBE
```

In ORACLE

```
SELECT count(*) as Total, hire_date 
FROM employees
WHERE extract(year from hire_date) IN ('1995','1996','1997','1998') 
GROUP BY CUBE (hire_date)
```

In addition to the subtotals generated by the GROUP BY, the CUBE extension will generate subtotals for each hire_date.

Comment: `year(hire_date)` is invalid in Oracle. Also you shouldn't compare numbers to strings. `'1995'` is not a number